Having issues swapping brett on base with my web3.py script
Here is my current code (not including abi because its gonna be to long)



#Addresses
PERMIT_ADDRESS  = '0x000000000022D473030F116dDEE9F6B43aC78BA3'
BRETT_ADDRESS   = '0x532f27101965dd16442E59d40670FaF5eBB142E4'
WETH_ADDRESS    = '0x7ceB23fD6bC0adD59E62ac25578270cFf1b9f619'
ROUTER_ADDRESS  = '0x3fC91A3afd70395Cd496C647d5a6CC9D4B2b7FAD'


def main():

  approve1 = approve_permit.build_transaction(tx)
  print ('[-] Approving permit... ')
  tx_hash = send_tx(sign_tx(approve1, eoa.key))
  receipt = w3.eth.wait_for_transaction_receipt(tx_hash)
  print (f'[+] Approved PERMIT2 at TOKEN contract: {tx_hash}\n[>] {receipt}')

  tx.update({'nonce': w3.eth.get_transaction_count(eoa.address)})

  approve2 = approve_router.build_transaction(tx)
  print ('[-] Approving router... ')
  tx_hash = send_tx(sign_tx(approve2, eoa.key))
  receipt = w3.eth.wait_for_transaction_receipt(tx_hash)
  print (f'[+] Approved ROUTER at PERMIT contract: {tx_hash}\n[>] {receipt}')

  tx.update({'nonce': w3.eth.get_transaction_count(eoa.address)})

  swap = router.functions.execute(commands, [v3_calldata], deadline).build_transaction(tx)
  print(swap)
  print('[-] Simulating swap...')
  #w3.eth.call(swap)
  print('[-] Attempting swap...')
  tx_hash = send_tx(sign_tx(swap, eoa.key))
  receipt = w3.eth.wait_for_transaction_receipt(tx_hash)
  print (f'[>] Hash of swap: {tx_hash}\n[>] {receipt}')

if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()

when I submit my txn into tenderly is show me that it is failing in the first line inside the ISwapRouter
txn: 0xf11ebcf1fded992c6077204aa265be3f635c1f1aa8f7e599c93af0ecabd4dc19
Anyone got any ideas ?

@cryptoLamer is correct, swapping for the base address allows the sim to go through successfully. Have modified the source example and responded to the issue on github.

I see the transaction is on Base, but the weth address on Base ain't the one specified in your code (0x7ceB23fD6bC0adD59E62ac25578270cFf1b9f619). The weth address on Base is 0x4200000000000000000000000000000000000006. So this is the reason your transaction failing - the V3 pool 0x6f64dd0961064ec3971b56d389da5211c7ffc547 (computed with the wrong weth address) does not exist, so can't perform a swap.
